# XPath to table cell (td) contents based upon label?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Can anyone help me to find the right XPath to retrieve the `Average Win` and `Loss value` (36.68 pips and -38.56 pips) from this web page:

https://www.myfxbook.com/members/babatrader/ic-markets-live/2595252

Here the portion of the HTML

```
<table class="maxWidth" cellspacing="0" id="trades">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="advanced border0L">
        <tbody><tr class="bg1">
            <td>Trades:</td>
            <td class="alignR">2885</td>
        </tr>



                                <tr>
            <td>Profitability:</td>
            <td align="right" class="pointer">
                        <span id="wonTip" class="Won 1619 out of 2885 trades, which represents 56%.<br/>Lost 1266 out of 2885 trades, which represents 44%."><div class="blockHolder">
                            <div class="greenBlock floatLeft" style="width:56px"></div>
                            <div class="redBlock floatLeft" style="width:44px"></div>
                        </div></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="bg1">
            <td>Pips:</td>
            <td class="alignR">10571.7</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Average Win:</td>
            <td class="alignR">36.68 pips / €3.31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg1">
            <td>Average Loss:</td>
            <td class="alignR">-38.56 pips / -€3.56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>    Lots:</td>
            <td class="alignR">38.94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg1">
            <td>Commissions:</td>
            <td class="alignR">-€226.56</td>
        </tr>


                                    </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table cellspacing="0" class="advanced border0R border0L">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>Longs Won:</td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <span class="gray">(687/1247) </span> 55%
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg1">
                    <td>Shorts Won:</td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <span class="gray">(932/1638) </span> 56%
                        </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Best Trade(€):</td>
                    <td class="alignR">                             <span class="gray">(Jul 20)</span> 17.93
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg1">
                    <td> Worst Trade(€):</td>
                    <td class="alignR">                            <span class="gray">(Jul 19)</span> -32.08
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Best Trade (Pips):</td>
                    <td class="alignR">                            <span class="gray">(Sep 07)</span> 177.5
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg1">
                    <td>Worst Trade (Pips):</td>
                    <td class="alignR">                            <span class="gray">(Sep 06)</span> -190.0
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Avg. Trade Length:</td>
                    <td class="alignR">
                        22h 45m
                    </td>
                </tr>

                                    </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table cellspacing="0" class="advanced border0R">
                <tbody><tr class="bg1">
                    <td><span class="dotted" id="pfTip">Profit Factor:</span></td>
                    <td class="alignR">
                                                                                 1.19
                                                                         </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="dotted" id="sdTip">Standard Deviation:</span></td>
                    <td class="alignR">€4.30</td>
                </tr>
                                                        <tr class="bg1">
                                                            <td><span class="dotted" id="sharpTip">Sharpe Ratio:</span></td>
                                             <td class="alignR">
                                                 0.00
                                             </td>
                                        </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td><span class="dotted" id="zTip">Z-Score (Probability):</span></td>
                    <td class="alignR">
                        -31.21 (99.99%)
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="bg1">
                    <td><span class="dotted" id="expTip">Expectancy:</span></td>
                    <td class="alignR">3.7 Pips / €0.30</td>
                </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span class="dotted" id="ahprTip">AHPR:</span></td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.01%</td>
                                        </tr>
                 <tr class="bg1">
                                                            <td><span class="dotted" id="ghprTip">GHPR:</span></td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.01%</td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

I've tried without succeed: The below is the one I have tried it.

```
    //*[@id="trades"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]

    //*[@id="trades"]/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
```

and many others.. ;-)

Comment: Can you try this //*[@id="trades"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
substring-before(//table[@id="trades"]
                 //td[.="Average Win:"]/following-sibling::td[1], " /")
```

will select

```
36.68 pips
```

as requested, and you should find it to be more robust than many alternatives.  For example, the table structure can change substantially, and as long as the label and the relative positions of the two table cells remain the same, this XPath will continue to function.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much!
Can i ask you a similar solution to extract the text "Won 1619 out of 2885 trades, which represents 56%." on line 15 of the same code? I would appreciate your help!

Comment: @adavide: Its element has an `@id`, so you ought to know that one: `//span[@id="wonTip"]/@class`.

Answer (score 0):

i had to remove both "tbody"

//*[@id='trades']/tr/td/table/tr[4]/td[2]